# Apache Pig - How to get the size of a record in KBs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How to get the memory size of a particular record (tuple) in Apache Pig ? Is there any function which helps us get that ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
You can try to use the builtin UDF **SIZE**.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/SIZE.html

So if you want to compute the size of the entire tuple, you will probably need to first cast all of the tuple fields to bytearray, then use SIZE on each of them, and finely summarize all of them together to get the tuple size in bytes.
Obviously You can convert it then to KB.